# How to set foreign key in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I Have a model named employee. The following is my migration file.

```
class CreateEmployees < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :employees, id: false do |t|
            t.string :name
            t.string :password
            t.string :role
            t.primary_key :name
        end
    end
end
```

Now, I want to create a model named "teamplayer" with the columns as 'name' which needs to refers 'name' column in employee model. And 'tl' column
which is independent to this model. The following is my "teamplayer" migration file.

```
class CreateTeamplayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :teamplayers, :id false do |t|
            t.string :tl
            t.string :name
        end
    end
end
```

In the above file, how to reference 'name' column to the model employee? So how to achieve foreign key in rails.

Comment: I'd not create a table without PK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look into Active Record Associations (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

I know you've asked to create a foreign key on `name` but unless you plan to ensure that name is unique, then this is possibly not the best plan (depending on the actual relationship you are trying to model - one to many / one to one etc).

I would be tempted to set up the foreign key relationship on `employees.id`. To do this, you can use the `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations.

You could change your `teamplayers` migration as follows:

```
class CreateTeamplayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teamplayers, :id false do |t|
        t.belongs_to :employee
        t.string :tl
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your `Employee` model, you can add the `has_many` side of things:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teamplayers
end
```

You can still easily get the Employee name given a Team Player record with a simple join.

Edit - to get the Employee, you can do something like this, assuming `@t`is a teamplayer instance:

```
@t.employee.name
```

(the code is untested and from memory so....)

Comment: How to refer 'name' column which is in 'employee' model in 'teamplayer' model ?

Comment: See the edit, but basically, if you have a teamplayer instance, you get the employee name with `@t.employee.name`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the teamplayer model, you just need to add index in your migration

```
class CreateTeamplayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teamplayers, :id false do |t|
        t.string :tl
        t.string :name
    end
    add_index :teamplayers, :name
  end
end
```

You can set name as Primary key inside the employee model like this

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "name"
  has_many :teamplayers
end
```

Now inside the model Teamplayer you can set the foreign key

```
class Teamplayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee, foreign_key: 'name'
end
```

This should reference 'name' to employee model